# Как мне опубликовать сайт на Github Pages через Github Actions и yaml файл?

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages, yaml, github-actions

Я написал сайт с использованием вальной JS. Он собран с помощью npm и index.html лежит внутри папки dist. Далее я подключил Github Actions и теперь мне нужен yaml файл, который будет при каждом новом пуше хостить мой index.html на github pages.
Я уже сам попробовал, но безуспешно(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZvYH.png)

До этого я пользовался просто GitHub pages, но сейчас собираю всё через npm пакеты и сохраняю в папку dist. Т.к. index.html теперь внутри неё, то я вынужден работать через Github actions, но я не понимаю как правильно и что писать в yaml файле, чтобы мой index.html отображался в github pages. Помогите пожалуйста

Вот, если что, моя структура папок(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aoCx.png)

Comment: Приведите yaml, которым пытались сделать

Comment: В целом, нужно пушить сгенерированный сайт в отдельную ветку (обычно gh-pages), потом ее в настройках pages указать. Есть даже готовый action для деплоя: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages